# Why use dom serializer when DOM object has .toString() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, serialization, xmldom

up to now, whenever I wanted to obtain the XML text that a DOM object represented, I used the `.serializeToString()` method. Example:

```
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var s = require('xmldom').XMLSerializer;

myNode = new dom().parseFromString('<greet>Hello!</greet>', 'text/xml');
console.log(new s().serializeToString(myNode, 'text/xml');
```

However, I have accidentally discovered that all node objects also have a `.toString()` method which, apparently, returns exactly the same thing as the serializer.

```
console.log(myNode.toString());
```

What is the point of going through the serializer? 
Is it best practice? 
Are there any important differences (for example, treatment of special characters like '<')? Anything else I should be made aware of?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that if you are only using this code on Node, then you are free to use either `node.toString()` or `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node)`.

The `toString` method is however non-standard, and does not exist in browsers. The [DOMParser](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/) spec only specifies the parsing/serializing in a few ways and `toString` is not one of them. As you can see in `XMLDOM`, it is just an alias to `serializeToString`:

https://github.com/jindw/xmldom/blob/master/dom.js#L911

Also note that `serializeToString` does not have a second argument, so you don't need the second `text/xml`.